# How to replace array values according to a value replace map in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

Assume I have an array:

```
$origin = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'];
```

and a replace map array:

```
$replace_map = [
    'value1' => 'replace1',
    'value2' => 'replace2',
    'value8' => 'replace8',
];
```

I want to replace the `$origin` array and expect the result to be:

```
$result = myReplace($origin, $replace_map);

$result = ['replace1', 'replace2', 'value3', 'value4'];
```

I can loop `$origin` and for each items lookup `$replace_map` by `array_key_exists`, and replace it with the value in `$replace_map`,

But I think this is not the best way, it sounds not efficient.

Is there better way to do this?

Further more, if the origin values are all integers, but some are negative, but the keys in map array are all positive,

like:

```
$origin = [-12345, 23456];
$map = [12345 => 98765];
```

also need change `-12345` to `-98765`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$origin = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', '-2'];

$replace_map = [
    'value1' => 'replace1',
    'value2' => 'replace2',
    'value8' => 'replace8',
    2 => 77 
];

$new = array_map(function($i) use($replace_map) {
                   return preg_replace_callback('/^(-)*(.+)$/', 
                         function($m) use($replace_map) {
                            if(!isset($replace_map[$m[2]]))
                              return($m[0]);
                            return $m[1] . $replace_map[$m[2]];
                         },$i); 
                   }, $origin);
print_r($new);
```

result

```
Array
(
    [0] => replace1
    [1] => replace2
    [2] => value3
    [3] => -77
)
```

Answer (score 5):

[str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) can handle arrays for search and replace parameters.

Try this code:

```
<?php
$origin = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'];
print_r($origin);
$search = ['value1', 'value2', 'value8'];
$replace = ['replace1', 'replace2', 'replace8'];
$result = str_replace($search, $replace, $origin);
print_r($result);
```

The output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
    [2] => value3
    [3] => value4
)
Array
(
    [0] => replace1
    [1] => replace2
    [2] => value3
    [3] => value4
)
```

Also, str_replace handles as elements as strings, therefore, also integers will be replaced. Partial matches will also be replaced, for example:

```
echo str_replace(2, 5, -200);
```

will result in -500.

Comment: Honestly didn't realise `str_replace` worked on subject arrays too

Answer (score 2):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/array_map) to run [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) on each of the array values, like so:

```
$origin = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'];
$result = array_map('myReplace', $origin);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';

function myReplace($value) {
    $replace_map = [
        'value1' => 'replace1',
        'value2' => 'replace2',
        'value8' => 'replace8',
    ];
    return str_replace(array_keys($replace_map), array_values($replace_map), $value);
}
```

Or for newer versions of PHP you can use an [anonymous function](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)

```
$replace_map = [
    'value1' => 'replace1',
    'value2' => 'replace2',
    'value8' => 'replace8',
];
$origin = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4'];
$result = array_map(function($value) use ($replace_map) {
    return str_replace(array_keys($replace_map), array_values($replace_map), $value);
}, $origin);
echo '<pre>' . print_r($result, true) . '</pre>';
```

Comment: It's good to know str_replace can handle arrays, but will it replace values that are partly matched, like replace `12345` to `98745` if in map there is 123 => 987 ?

Comment: In that case it's best to use `preg_replace` matching the entire string

Answer (score 0):

I think there is much room for improvement in @splash58's unexplained answer.  `preg_replace_callback()` can receive array type data as its 3rd parameter so the `array_map()` wrapper is not necessary.  The inner workings can be simplified too.

The other answers that are employing `str_replace()` cannot be trusted because they will make partial replacements. @Alexander admits this in his answer, but JamieBicknell admits it in a comment. [@JamieBicknell's replaces multiple partial matches](https://3v4l.org/sbqED)

Since the leading negative symbol should not be replaced, we make it an optional match that we do not replace.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/uSNDj))

```
$origin = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', '-2', '2', '22'];

$replace_map = [
    'value1' => 'replace1',
    'value2' => 'replace2',
    'value8' => 'replace8',
    2 => 77
];

var_export(
    preg_replace_callback(
        '~^-?\K.*$~',
        function($m) use($replace_map) {
            return $replace_map[$m[0]] ?? $m[0];
        },
        $origin
    )
);
```

If you are on PHP7.4 or higher, the syntax can be made more brief by using arrow function syntax.

```
var_export(
    preg_replace_callback('~^-?\K.*$~', fn($m)=> $replace_map[$m[0]] ?? $m[0], $origin)
);
```

Output (from both snippets):

```
array (
  0 => 'replace1',
  1 => 'replace2',
  2 => 'value3',
  3 => '-77',
  4 => '77',
  5 => '22',
)
```